# Function call stack _dummy_computation_fn, I am getting this error when training my Object Detection Model

Tags: object, detection

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node ResNet101V1_FPN/model/conv1_conv/Conv2D:
ResNet101V1_FPN/model/lambda/Pad (defined at /local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/models/keras_models/resnet_v1.py:51)

Function call stack:
_dummy_computation_fn

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working with Tensorflow-gpu==2.6.0 when I encountered this problem. After searching and seeing many suggestions.
I believe TF 2.6.0 isn't having a compatible version with CuDNN 8, so I downgrade the TF to 2.4.1 `!pip --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1` and it worked.
Another suggestion is to uninstall TensorFlow and tensoflow-gpu and Restart runtime after that, Install the version of TensorFlow you want.

Possible Solutions:

1. Reduce Batch_size from 64 to 8 or 4 or lower.
2. Restart Runtime and uninstall all Tensorflow-gpu versions.

I hope my answer will help.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I was training an object detection model using efficientDet_D0 on colab and what solved my issue was simply to change to a TPU runtime. Also as @Ahmad Abubakar mentioned you should try reducing your batchsize to something smaller. I find that anything less than 10 works best for me